# Running ray head with external redis

Tags: redis, ray

I'm setting up the infrastructure for a Ray project and would like to use an external redis (i.e one not started by `ray --head`. However that currently does not seem possible, giving me:

`If --head is passed in, a Redis server will be started, so a Redis address should not be provided.`

Has anyone managed to use an external Redis not managed by Ray?

Regards,
Niklas

Answer (score 0):

There's an ongoing project to improve this limitation. https://github.com/ray-project/ray/pull/6763

The idea is to make GCS as a service that you can use various external backends.